# Accessing variables that are inside a function

Tags: python, module

I was looking all over for any kind of small example or something to help me and I couldn't find it. I feel like I am missing something obvious. I have a large function in one .py file that I want to call in another .py file and use all the variables from the function and I couldn't do it. So I was trying to do it with a small example and still can't get it. Say I have a file mod1.py that contains:

```
def mod(num):
    a = 5
    b = 6
    c = num
```

I tried adding all kinds of returns to it and still couldn't get it to work. But I call it in a file named mod_read.py:

```
import mod1

mod1.mod(1)
d = mod1.mod.a
print(d)
```

When I run mod_read.py I get the error: "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'a'". What obvious thing am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Local variables only exist while the function is being run.
2. Local variables are never attributes of their containing function.

If you want to get values from a function then you need to return them from it. Otherwise, look into OOP if you need more persistence.

Comment: or define your variables in global scope within your functions like `global a, b,c d`  though considered a bad programming practice

Comment: @QuakiGabbar Classes exist to manage variables shared by functions. Accordingly, there is no need to define global variables which will be reassigned.

Answer (score 1):

You can return multiple values from a function as tuple:

```
def mod(num):
    a = 5
    b = 6
    c = num
    return (a, b, num)
```

Then in the other file, use it something like this:

```
import mod1

d, b, num = mod1.mod(1)
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't use variables from another function. You call a function, and you get its return value - that is the point of a function (or to cause whatever side effects it causes).

If you want a thing which stores values in variables, you want to use *objects*. Define a class.

In your particular example, I don't know what "all kinds of returns" means, but if you want the function to return `a`, just do `return a`:

```
def mod(num):
    a = 5
    b = 6
    c = num
    return a
```

Comment: I understand that is what most functions are used for. However, I'm using a function to unpack a binary output file. The file contains probably 100 different values solved for a fluid flow problem and I was looking for a way to not have to type out a return for all of them.

Comment: @Jane Did you get past the first paragraph? Use an object, or perhaps a dict.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that idea. If I created a class to contain all the information I need, do I then return the class? Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: @Jane You will return an object instantiated from the class, and put the values in the object. That is to say: 1. write the class 2. write a function which instantiates an object of that class 3. write the part of the function which puts the data in the object.